# Как сделать рендер нужного роутера в react-router, вбивая адрес в адресную строку?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

К сожалению, я не знаю, как продемонстрировать работу `react-router` хоть здесь, хоть на codepen, потому попробую объяснить как есть.

Вот так выглядит код:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import {Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
const Home = () => <p>Home page</p>;
const Search = () => <p>Search page</p>;

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/search">Search</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
        </Switch>

    </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/4.3.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Вот так выглядит результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю на ссылку, перехожу куда нужно, все работает нормально.

Но, если я хочу ввести в адресную строку тот же самый путь: `/search`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это не работает.

Как на `react-router` сделать правильный переход к нужному роутеру из адресной строки

Comment: а какой сервер? `express` на ноде?

Comment: вам нужно сервер настроить так, что бы он отдавал `index.html` при запросе по адресу `/search` и вообще при любом таком адресе

Comment: И тогда точно сработает router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить ваш сервер так, что бы он при запросе какого-то адреса выдавал всегда `index.html`

Для `nginx`:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951720/react-router-and-nginx)